# how construct a proper foreach()

Tags: pdo, foreach

guys at start i must notice... im a noob at all :)

i try to run script on local windows machine (IIS, PHP 5.2, MSSQL) and got error:

```
PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: table in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\XX.php on line 38
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\XX.php on line 12
```

Script:

```
<?php
$user = 'xx';
$pass = 'xx';
$host = '10.0.2.15';
$dbname = 'Game3G';
try{
$dbh = new PDO ("mssql:host=$host;dbname=$dbname", "$user", "$pass");
$n=0;  
function sorting($next,$table) {
$temp=0;

foreach($table as $entry) if($entry['position']==0) if($entry['level']>=$temp['level'] && $entry['exp']>=$temp['exp']) $temp=$entry;
if($temp) {
$table[$temp['id']]['position']=$next;
echo '<tr>
     <td width="20px" style="font-size: 10px;">'.$next.'</td><td width="80px" style="font-size: 10px;">'.$temp['character'].'</td><td style="font-size: 10px;">'.$temp['level'].'</td> <td  width="30px" style="font-size: 10px; text-align: right;">'.$temp['exp'].'%</td>
     </tr>
   ';
sorting($next+1,$table);
}
}


echo '<br> <table width="170"  border=0  >';
$i=0;
foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_LEVEL, TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_jOB, TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_CHARACTER, TBL_ABILITY.FLD_MAXEXP, TBL_ABILITY.FLD_EXP from TBL_CHARACTER LEFT JOIN TBL_ABILITY ON(TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_CHARACTER = TBL_ABILITY.FLD_CHARACTER) where TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_LEVEL < 69 and TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_jOB = 2 and TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_DELETED = 0 order by TBL_ABILITY.FLD_EXP + TBL_ABILITY.FLD_LEVEL * TBL_ABILITY.FLD_MAXEXP desc') as $row)
{
$i++;
$table[$i-1]['level']=$row['FLD_LEVEL'];
$table[$i-1]['character']=$row['FLD_CHARACTER'];
$table[$i-1]['exp']=round(($row['FLD_EXP']/$row['FLD_MAXEXP'])*100);
$table[$i-1]['id']=$i-1;
$table[$i-1]['position']=0;

$n++;
 if($n>=10) break;
};
sorting(1,$table);
echo '</table><br>';
$dbh = null;    
 }
 catch(PDOException $e){
     echo 'Statystyki niedostępne.';
 }  
/*end*/            
?>
```

script schould generate table with characters stats (game server). Im sure its worked on other machine, propably diferent php version.
Could someone of you tune this code for php v5.2.1 ?

THX

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is clearly highlighted in the error message you recieve.  When you call `sorting(1,$table);` the variable $table hasn't been defined (which is line 38, as the error message says), so when your function tries to run line 12: `foreach($table as $entry)` the for-loop fails because a for-loop only takes an array, and what you've asked it to loop over is an unset, or null value.

But I set the `$table` variable in my other loop I hear you say!  Well you try, but as  PHPStorm helpfully highlights: [image]

Because you assume the query has run successfully and also returned at least one row here: `foreach ($dbh->query('SELECT TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_LEVEL, TBL_C`....  but never check you run the risk of passing an uninstantiated variable.

So what can you do?  well either declare your `$table` variable somewhere before you try to add anything to it so that it's always at least a valid result.

More sensibly though I would take your query out of the foreach and store the result somewhere, then you can check if you have any data and deal with the situation appropriately if you don't have any e.g.

```
$result = $dbh->query('SELECT TBL_CHARACTER.FLD_LEVEL, TBL_CHARAC....fetchAll()....

then say 
if(sizeof($result) > 0) {

     foreach($result as $row){
     \\\do all your stuff here
     }
} else {
      //output something useful 
}
```

a few other things that seem unusual in your code are

```
$i++;
$table[$i-1]['level']=$row['FLD_LEVEL'];
```

why are you incrementing $i, and then subtracting 1 every time?  Wouldn't it make more sense to just do the increment at the end? But anyway, you don't need to do the increment at all becase you could just do this:

```
$array = ['level' =>$row['FLD_LEVEL'],['character' => $row['FLD_CHARACTER'] ....];

 $table[] = $array;
```

and then it would automatically be indexed correctly.  The only reason do do this increment is if you need specific index on the items but i can't see that you are doing that

I also can't see any point for using this:

```
$n++;
if($n>=10) break;
```

you're incrementing $i and you're incrementing $n they are both the same value, so just choose one of them, or don't increment anything and say (assuming your result is in an index array and you're not fetching keys or anything)

```
foreach($result as $key => $row){

  if($key > 9) break;//because it starts at zero, key 9 = 10 iterations, so > 9 is our limit
  //sensibly building your array

}
```

In short I don't believe this is anything to do with the PHP version.  But anyway, you ought to upgrade to php7, though I appreciate that may be outside of your control